# Python: Check list of dictionaries with unknown size for certain conditions

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm pretty sure it's a beginners question, but I just can't find the solution for my problem. So I am thankful for every sort of help.

My list of dictionaries with an unknown amount of entries and order looks something like this:

```
list_of_dict = [
    {'value_a': '100', 'value_b': '25'},
    {'value_a': '200', 'value_b': '10'},
    {'value_a': '200', 'value_b': '17'},
    {'value_a': '100', 'value_b': '25'},
]
```

There are multiple conditions to find out, whether the list fits all my needs. One condition is to check, if the list only contains exact pairs of dictionaries. The list above would be a failure, since the second and third entry are containing different values for key 'value_b'. Here are some more examples to explain my problem:

```
# True
list_of_dict = [
    {'value_a': '100', 'value_b': '25'},
    {'value_a': '200', 'value_b': '10'},
    {'value_a': '200', 'value_b': '10'},
    {'value_a': '100', 'value_b': '25'},
]

# False
list_of_dict = [
    {'value_a': '100', 'value_b': '25'},
    {'value_a': '200', 'value_b': '10'},
    {'value_a': '100', 'value_b': '25'},
]

# True
list_of_dict = [
    {'value_a': '100', 'value_b': '25'},
    {'value_a': '100', 'value_b': '25'},
]

# False
list_of_dict = [
    {'value_a': '100', 'value_b': '25'},
    {'value_a': '200', 'value_b': '10'},
]
```

Only exception are lists with only one entry - these are always fitting my needs.

Thanks and have a greate day!

Comment: I think you forgot to include your attempt and error(s) if any that you encountered

Comment: What if the same dict appears four times (i.e., two pairs)?

Comment: Do the dicts always have exactly those two keys (perhaps even always in that order?) and string values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created an `isPaired` function that does just that:

```py
# True
list1 = [ {'value_a': '100', 'value_b': '25'}, {'value_a': '200', 'value_b': '10'}, {'value_a': '200', 'value_b': '10'}, {'value_a': '100', 'value_b': '25'}, ]
 
# False
list2 = [ {'value_a': '100', 'value_b': '25'}, {'value_a': '200', 'value_b': '10'}, {'value_a': '100', 'value_b': '25'}, ]
 
# True
list3 = [ {'value_a': '100', 'value_b': '25'}, {'value_a': '100', 'value_b': '25'}, ]
 
# False
list4 = [ {'value_a': '100', 'value_b': '25'}, {'value_a': '200', 'value_b': '10'}, ]


def isPaired(l):
 if len(l) == 1: return True # For your exception
 unpairedDicts = [] # Store which dictionaries (dicts) have been "counted for" in the list
 for dic in l:
  if dic in unpairedDicts: unpairedDicts.remove(dic)
  else: unpairedDicts.append(dic)
 return not unpairedDicts

print(isPaired(list1)) # For testing
```

Hope you understand the logic. Have a nice day too :)